# Watch Window doesn't display properties of EntityFramework proxies

Tags: entity-framework-core, visual-studio-2019, watch, debuggervisualizer

The watch window in Visual Studio 2019 has worked fine until yesterday (I believe my laptop may have rebooted over night due to an update pushed by sys admins).

Now, when I set a breakpoint and try to evaluate the properties of an entity, the entity proxy doesn't display the properties (or values):

[VS 2019 Watch window with blank properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dg0RF.png)

The Watch is aware of the number of properties as it lists an icon for each, but the property names and values are blank. 
Also, if I type the property name directly (e.g. detail.Asset.Id) it will display the value.

Has anyone seen this? know the cause? and/or know how to fix?

Comment: "_Did you try turning it off and on again"_?

Comment: I did. It didn't work. I updated VS, didn't help. I ran the repair. I think the restart after the repair failed when I walked away from the computer. When I came back to login, it didn't work, but another reboot and it started working again!

Answer (score 0):

Repair/reboot seems to have fixed it.